# Is Mathematica compatible with primusrun?

Tags: graphics3d, linux, compatibility, ubuntu, rendering

I use *Mathematica* 9 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86 (64-bit). My computer has an Nvidia graphics card, for which I installed `primus` and `bumblebee`. If anyone is in a similar situation, I would like to know if they have solutions to the following two related problems:

1. *Mathematica* does not need OpenGL when it's not rendering any 3D graphics. For this reason I find it convenient to run the program without `optirun mathematica` or `primusrun mathematica` most of the time. However, I noticed that if I do make a `Plot3D` or related command, *Mathematica* will crash. Is it possible to set the program up in a way so that it doesn't crash, but rather shows an error message, or just doesn't show output, if no 3D rendering is possible?
2. `primusrun` extends `optirun` functionality by saving power when the graphics card is not in use. I suppose that for this reason, if I'm not actively rotating a 3D graphic, it goes blank in a session of `primusrun mathematica` rather than `optirun mathematica`. When using the less efficient `optirun`, all functionality is available and runs as expected. Did anyone figure out a workaround for this?

I'm asking on this site rather than AskUbuntu because the solution, if it exists, probably lies in changing *Mathematica* preferences rather than `primus`'.

Comment: There's a misconception about the power saving.  To clarify, primusrun avoids powering on the discrete GPU as long as the application does not load the OpenGL library; after that, power saving compared to optirun/virtualgl may come from obeying vsync, but that probably wouldn't matter for Mathematica.

As noted below, consider filing a bug with reproduction steps for the blank 3D figure in primus.

Comment: @amonakov - yes, like I said, this was only my guess as to why the blank graphics occur. I agree it's due to some more complicated bug.  I already filed a report to Wolfram support but I seriously doubt they would be able to help such a niche use case (i.e. Linux users with Optimus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must adjust the Antialiasing Quality to solve that issue. Go to menu Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics.. then adjust it.. That worked for me. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Mathematica V9.

Other solution is open a terminal and run: mathematica -mesa when opening.

Comment: Hi ! Can you edit your post to clarify it ? As it is currently written it is hard to tell exactly which issue/s you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yep. This solution works on Linux Mint 17.1 as well. +1

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1 should be a distribution specific bug. I cannot reproduce this problem on Archlinux.

I can reproduce problem 2. I think primusrun is still experimental. You may report a bug to them (but the developers may not have Mathemataica though).

Comment: If you can provide reproduction steps for the trial version, or capture the problem with apitrace, I will look into fixing it.  Consider filing a bug at https://github.com/amonakov/primus/issues

Comment: Thanks! I filed a bug at github.

Comment: What happens for Problem 1 for you?

Comment: On my computer, Mathematica works well, no crash, and displays Plot3D figures correctly when started directly using integrated graphics (i.e. without optirun or primusrun)

Comment: Problem 2 is a limitation in primus, it doesn't support GLX pixmaps and front buffer rendering: https://github.com/amonakov/primus/issues/131


Regarding problem 1, you may be seeing a segfault in graphics drivers: 12.04 is quite old.

Comment: @amonakov Thanks for the info - I feel lucky that there's someone like you using Mathematica.SE! For problem 1, is it a matter of updating drivers or OS?

Answer (score 2):

After talking with Wolfram tech support, it seems problem 1 is really just [this issue](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3303) resolved by running Mathematica by the `mathematica -mesa` command.

Problem 2 is unresolved. I suppose I should keep this question open, though I don't know if a fix will come soon.